# Dynamically generated image non loading iframe IE8

Tags: jquery, iframe

we have iframe

```
<iframe src="m1.html">
</iframe>
<div style"display:none"><p>contents</p>
<img src="url-session-data" />
<div>
```

through jquery, we are loading div contents to iframe ,
problem is image is not loading in IE8 but working fine in IE6,FF etc

any suggestion?

Note: url-session-data is dynamic loading

Answer (score 1):

Your iframe might not be ready even when document itself is. Use frameready jquery plugin: http://ideamill.synaptrixgroup.com/?p=6
For IE8 it takes more time to process the frame. This get IE6 to work well.

Answer (score 0):

**`<div style"display:none">`**

Should not show image because it is inside of a  that is set to not display contents